# text boxes in html form going beyond borders of form

Tags: html, forms, css, textbox, border

I am making a form in HTML that contains two text boxes and one text area, and I would like for all three elements to share a common width value. However, if I use `width: 100%`, referring to 100% of the form width, the text boxes stretch past the right border of the form. (Red border in the picture link indicates form border).

Picture:
[image: Code Displayed in Browser]

As you can see in the image above, the textboxes extend past the right border of the form, approximately about half as much as the padding of the form. Is there anyway to make the textboxes display properly (with correct padding all around the form)?

In addition, a very close look reveals that the `<textarea>` box is slightly less wide than the others (approx. 2px); however, it is set to the same width (100%). Any ideas what causes this?

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
form
{
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px dashed red;
}

input[type=text], input[type=email], textarea
{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: x-large;
}

input[type=text], input[type=email]
{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

textarea
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="frmContact">
    <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" placeholder="Name *">
    <input type="email" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" placeholder="Email *">
    <textarea id="txtComments" name="txtComments" placeholder="Comments *"
                  maxlength="500"></textarea>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, an element's `padding` is not included in its `width`/`height` dimensions. In your example, the elements were extending beyond the parent element because there was `10px` of padding on each side of the elements.

`100%` + `20px` `!=` `100%`

You could add [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to the elements in order to include the `padding` in the element's `width`/`height` calculations.

[**Updated Exmaple**](http://jsfiddle.net/4k7cmrk9/)

```
input[type=text], input[type=email], textarea {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: x-large;
}
```